# How to print a double-sided, tiled print from an InDesign file?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design

I have a 22in x 69in chart that I need to print tiled from InDesign CC. It is double-sided. Can I print both sides as 1 tiled print, so I don't have to assemble both sides separately?

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up doing was first printing the front side, tiled. Then I re-loaded those prints back into the printer and printed the back side, tiled.

The tricky part was figuring out the right order to reload those front-side prints. Just reloading the prints in the same order did not work. I had to essentially pull my even pages out and put them ahead of my odd pages. (Pages 1, 2, 3, 4 were re-ordered as pages 2, 1, 4, 3 etc.) This worked -

I could never get the prints to come out correctly by tiling a double-sided print in one step. (btw: I'm using a Xerox 4595 copier for proof output.)

Thank you so much for your reply and I sincerely apologize for my delay in responding.

Answer (score 1):

No automatic way that I can think of, but you could still technically accomplish this by "assembling" it digitally before printing to paper. This may be more work than assembling them separately physically though.

If you really wanted to go for it though...

First, I'd print both the front and back separately as tiled, but instead of sending to the printer for paper output, print as a PDF.

Then, you'd still need to "assemble" the pages by merging the two PDFs together in to a single PDF document, odd pages being the front of the finished print, and even pages being the back. This would also be tricky because you'd need to figure out what back side pairs up with each front. For example, page 1 would likely be the top-**left** tile of the front side, but page 2 (the back of page 1) would be the top-**right** tile of the backside.

Also keep in mind that automated duplex on printers is often not perfect, and sometimes not even consistent.

Best of luck!